# How to convert autocomplete textview selected item into Place Object

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an autocomplete textview in my app that would let user enter address and the textview uses Places Api to show them different places that start with those letters the user is using. I implemented the Places Api and the user is able to see places but when they select a place I would like to retrieve that place and use it according to my needs(like retrieving the LatLng, and stuff like that) but the place object is String object and I don't know how to retrieve it as Place or convert the String object to Place object. I tried the following so far to no avail.
This is my adapter class.

```
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int list, int textViewResourceId) {

            super(context, list, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

msg.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.search_results_list_item, R.id.tvSearchResultItem));
        msg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String selectedPlace = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Place pl = new Place() {
                    @Override
                    public String getId() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public List<Integer> getPlaceTypes() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence getAddress() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Locale getLocale() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence getName() {
                        return selectedPlace;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public LatLng getLatLng() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public LatLngBounds getViewport() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Uri getWebsiteUri() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence getPhoneNumber() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public float getRating() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getPriceLevel() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Place freeze() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isDataValid() {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                LatLng selectedltlng = getSelectedLatLng(pl);
                Log.e("selected", selectedltlng.toString());
                //Place selectedPlace = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, );
                //Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            private LatLng getSelectedLatLng(Place placeStringe) {
                LatLng placeltlg = placeStringe.getLatLng();
                Log.e("selcete", placeltlg.toString());
                return placeltlg;
            }
        });
```

But this throws a null pointer exception. 
I also tried to cast the string object as Object like this

```
Object selectedPlace = (Object) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
Place plac = (Place)selectedPlace;
```

But this throws cast exception. How can I do that in an efficient way?

Comment: What type of data did you pass to your adapter object?

Comment: @NollyJ application context and textview to my custom class that implements arrayadapter.

Comment: Can you upload this file content - GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter

Comment: I just did. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You need to ArrayList<HashMap<String, PlaceObject>> to replace resultList. Also change Override
public String getItem(int index) {
     return resultList.get(index);
}  to Override
Public HashMap<String, PlaceObjec> getItem(int index) {
   return resultList.get(index);
}

Comment: I appreciate your help but I have a question. On the first line you said replace resultList but you are still requiring the getItem to return resultList.get(index). Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I made a city selector a week ago. It use custom extended AutoCompleteTextView widget. May be this helps you. This widget allows user to enter chars (grey color) and then show list of matched cities. User select a city from the list (it became black) and then selected city saved in cityData object and could be retrived by .getCity() call.

Here is the code:

```
public class CityAutoCompleteEditText extends AutoCompleteTextView implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcherAdapter.TextWatcherListener {

    // City object (code, name, type, level and so on)
    private OKTMOUnit cityData;

    // One of the constructors. You need to implement all with init() inside
    public CityAutoCompleteEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    // Initial data setter
    public void setCity(OKTMOUnit city) {
        setText(city.toString());
        setTextColor(resource_black);
        cityData = city;
    }

    // Data getter
    public OKTMOUnit getCity() {
        return cityData;
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        ......
        super.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // On click - set color black and init cityData
                cityData = (OKTMOUnit) getAdapter().getItem(position);
                setTextColor(resource_black);
            }
        });
        .....
     }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(EditText view, String text) {
        // Text changed by hand - grey it and clear cityData
        cityData = null;
        setTextColor(resource_grey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (cityData == null) {
            setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

And adapter:

```
public class CityAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 20;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<OKTMOUnit> mData;

    public CityAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OKTMOUnit getItem(int index) {
        return mData.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }
        if (convertView != null) {
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteCity)).setText(getItem(position).getFullCity());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteRegion)).setText(getItem(position).getFullRegion());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ADD: I removed `public Filter getFilter() {}` code from adapter to simplify it.

Comment: @Alexander Shutko While I appreciate your help, I would rather make my  adapter return a place object or somehow convert the String retrieved to place object, which shouldn't be complicated if Google thought about carefully and improve how they handle the docs.

Comment: This is edittext with hints. It can contain any junk you can imagine. You can't convert entered junk String into place. Users not always click autocomplete helpers. You can call setOnItemClickListener() and then do getAdapter().getItem(). 

I think you just need to make another getItem() without toString() call

Answer (score 0):

try this It is done with Model Class u can get place name,address,lat,long I found very useful http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-google-places-api/